# Question about linear combinations

Tags: linear-algebra

I am in my second semester of being a freshman in university and my instructor gave us a problem as follows:

[image: screenshot of the problem]

I did matrix eliminations to find the value of $u_1$ and $u_2$ but as I am going on, I realized that I really don’t know what to do with it. If someone could please give me a hint of what to do, I will try to do it and then post the results here. Thank you so much. And I am really sorry for my English.

This is a screenshot of the attempts I have done:

[image: attempt screenshot]

Comment: just substitute $v_1$ and $v_2$ in $w$

Comment: @ChinnapparajR thank you so much! I was able to solve it! I am really lacking in these kind of simple problems. I was not able to come up with that thinking. I really appreciate you.

Comment: glad to be of help!  Dont worry. Keep on problem solving. You will definitley learn in practice!